# A smarter way to write a function that uses a lot of conditional statements to return incremental values based on a different number ranges?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a function to return a certain value if the input is between a certain number range.

Normally, I would just write a series of if/else if statements to do the job. But, I'm working with a large number of ranges so writing out 30+ if/else if statements seems inefficient.

Let's say I have a set min and max number for the overall range and I want to break that up into smaller ranges. For each range, I want to return some value. Ideally, the return value for each range will decrease by some set number.

For context, I'm trying to use something similar to this to calculate a value based on mileage. For example, if the mileage is between 101-120 miles, the rate is equal to 80% of the mileage. As the mileage increases, the percentage decreases. And, the number that the percentage decreases by can be some set number (`-0.05` for example)

```
...
else if (m >= 101 && m <= 120) return 0.80
else if (m >= 121 && m <= 140) return 0.75
...
```

Since there is a pattern to the return values for each range, I'm thinking this can be done in a better way than just writing out a bunch of if/else statements but I'm not sure exactly how that can be done. Any ideas?

Comment: There is some inconsistency in your example: there are 16 integer values for which you return 0.95, while for the other return values there are each 10 integer values for `x`. If you harmonise that, it is a matter of a simple mathematical formula

Comment: Also, your ranges do not increment by 15. They increment by `10` - besides the first one (`0..15`). Also you have a demo-typo `=>` - and also what @trincot already pointed out

Comment: you could have an array of objects that specify the min/max value and the return value   for that range (or just a set of max values if you're always starting at 0), and then just loop through them until you find the right band.  I don't know that it's any more efficient, but it probably feels a little better than hard-coded if's.  And you could probably build the array itself with a for-loop or something similar

Comment: Seems like you lack a bit of detail, I'd revise the question a bit and be a bit more specific with expected output/etc. There's many ways to make this super efficient just missing some context.

Comment: Also... you never need to return `1` as the result value? You start immediately at `0.95` even for input entry `0`?

Comment: Also, FYI, 0..14(incl.) are 15 states. 0..15(incl.) are 16 states. And if it's true what you wrote in the description that increments should by 15, the next sets should be 15..29 30..44 45..59 etc. I presume your code demo (due to the too many typos) was a miss. Should we stick to the question description or?...

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76917176/a-smarter-way-to-write-a-function-that-uses-a-lot-of-conditional-statements-to-r?noredirect=1#comment135596034_76917176) `for (const [min, max, rate] of [[101, 120, 0.8], [121, 140, 0.75]/* etc */]) if (m >= min && m <= max) return rate;`

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesnt increment by 15; so, I'm assuming that was a typo.

The solution I would use is a function.
ie.

```js
(() => {

// in your example you have it .95 -> .9 -> .85 thus this starts at 1.
const STARTING_RETURN_VALUE = 1;

// the range increment your if statement has is 15
const INCREMENT = 15;

// this is the value in which the return value decreases by per interval
const DECREASING_RETURN_VALUE = .05;

const getReturn = (x, increment, starting_return_value, decreasing_return_value) => {
     return starting_return_value - (Math.floor(x/increment)+1)*decreasing_return_value;
}

console.log(getReturn(29, INCREMENT, STARTING_RETURN_VALUE, DECREASING_RETURN_VALUE));

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
console.log('112->', computeRate( 0.95, 0.05, 100, 20, 112 )); // 0,9
console.log('133->', computeRate( 0.95, 0.05, 100, 20, 133 )); // 0,85
console.log('164->', computeRate( 0.95, 0.05, 100, 20, 164 )); // 0,75
console.log('250->', computeRate( 0.95, 0.05, 100, 20, 250 )); // 0,55 


function computeRate( percenTop, percenDec, toptest, step, value )
  {
  let min  = 0
    , max  = toptest
    , resp = percenTop
    ;
  while ( (!(value >= min && value <= max)) && resp > 0)
    {
    min  += step; // min += step +1;  is not necessary;
    max  += step;
    resp = (resp - percenDec).toFixed(2);  // to fix float numbers matters
    }
  return Number.parseFloat(resp);
  }
```

OR, with a closure:

```js
const mileage = computeRate( 0.95, 0.05, 100, 20 );

console.log('112 ->', mileage( 112 )); // 0,9
console.log('133 ->', mileage( 133 )); // 0,85
console.log('164 ->', mileage( 164 )); // 0,75
console.log('22222 ->', mileage( 22222 )); // 0 


function computeRate( percenTop, percenDec, toptest, step )
  {
  return (value) =>
    {    
    let min  = 0
      , max  = toptest
      , resp = percenTop
      ;
    while ( (!(value >= min && value <= max)) && resp > 0)
      {
      min  += step; 
      max  += step;
      resp = (resp - percenDec).toFixed(2); // fix float numbers matters
      }
    return Number.parseFloat(resp);
    }
  }
```